# The control or subform control is too large for this location on resize

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple form in Access 2003.  The form has a List control and a button.  I wanted to make the list to resize with the form (only vertically) while the button remains at the bottom right of the List.  I'm using the following code on the form's resize event.

```
list.Height = Me.InsideHeight - list.Top - 200
commandButton.Top = list.Height + list.Top + 50
```

This works fine as I resize the form, until the form height gets to a certain height. Then I get this error;

> Run-time error '2100':
>   The control or subform control is too large for this location

This error is occurring at the line where I'm assigning the **commandButton.Top**.  If I remove this line then the list height changes fine.  I don't have any subforms in the form.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you need to resize the detail section of the form first.

Try changing the code to

```
Me.Section(0).Height = Me.InsideHeight 
list.Height = Me.InsideHeight - list.Top - 200 
commandButton.Top = list.Height + list.Top + 50
```

Comment: Are you some sort of Access genius or something? Thanks for that, works great now.

Comment: Not a genius but Access 2003 has been my day job for the past 5 years. Glad it is working for you now.

Comment: Not meaning to say anything about @Croberts level of knowledge, but why would you (@Sivakanesh) think you could resize the contents of a form control without making sure that the form section itself was large enough to contain the enlarged control?

Comment: It is possible in .net. The controls just don't shows because they don't fit, but are still there.

Answer (score 2):

I get this same error if I set the width to greater the 31680.

With a little more research, I notice MS Access only allows a form width to be 22" wide. 22" = 31680 TWIPS.

So my workaround solutions it to add a check:
If newWidth > 31680 Then newWidth = 31680

Answer (score 0):

Came by here (as many have) with the same problem and then realised my issue. Be mindful when resizing a control to a larger size with regard to the order of setting properties.
I would recommend setting the TOP and LEFT positions before HEIGHT and WIDTH.
Although my final sized control should have fitted OK once resized, I had originally tried setting the WIDTH first which attempted to enlarge the control exceeding the width of the form. My application threw the 2100 error at that point. I really hope this helps someone! Also, don't forget to set dimensions in TWIPS which is set as INCHESS x 1440 (or CM x 566.9291), ie: .Width = 10 * 566.9291 to set a control width to 10cm.